# Iterating through a dictionary of <Object, List> mappings. Django Tempates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm passing a django template , an argument like :

```
{'dict' : {Object0:[object1, object2, object3,.....], Object1:[object4, object5], ... } }
```

Is there anyway to iterate through that dictionary inside the template ?
Something like this wouldn't work :

```
{% for obj in dict  %}  
    {% for objs in dict.obj %}
              {# do sth here ... #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, iterating through a dict just iterates through its keys. You want the values:

```
{% for obj in dict.values %}
    {% for item in obj %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you need both keys and values, you could use `items`:

```
{% for key, value in dict.items %}
```

Comment: With the caveat that depending on the ordering of the keys, the objects may not be in order if object1..9 is expected (although, that could just be an example)...

Comment: Thanks , didn't know if '.items' works in django templates or not :)

Comment: It's just a method on the dictionary object, generally those will work as long as you don't need to pass any parameters.